# CSS trick for avoiding extra class when displaying thumbnails

Tags: css, css-float

i'm displaying 4x3 thumbnails inside my content wrapper using the following class for the thumbnails:

```
.thumbnail
{
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

the markup is:

```
<div class=wrapper>
    <div class=thumbnail></div>
    <div class=thumbnail></div>
    <div class=thumbnail></div>
    <div class=thumbnail></div>

    <div class=thumbnail></div>
    <div class=thumbnail></div>
    <div class=thumbnail></div>
    <div class=thumbnail></div>

    <div class=thumbnail></div>
    <div class=thumbnail></div>
    <div class=thumbnail></div>
    <div class=thumbnail></div>
</div>
```

the problem is that i need to assign an extra class to each 4th thumbnail which has `margin-right:0px`, otherwise it would not fit into the content wrapper and will look messy like this:

```
   __   __   __
| |__| |__| |__|     |
|  __   __   __      |
| |__| |__| |__|     |
|  __   __   __      |
| |__| |__| |__|     |
```

is there a better way to avoid this extra class?
thanks

**EDIT:** i found out that i can use div.wrapper img:nth-child(4n) but will this also work crossbrowser?

Comment: Can we see your markup and rest of the code to understand the problem more?

Comment: I think `nth-child` doesn't work in IE 8 and less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you comfortable with adding an extra wrapping `div`?

If so, you can use the old bootstrap 2.3.2 grid approach - shift the extra wrapper to the left by using negative margin, and using `margin-left` instead of `margin-right` for thumbnails:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>

        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row {
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.thumbnail {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AEguK/)** (widths are reduced a bit)

Comment: Another option is change parent's width to more then 100%

Answer (score 0):

```
.thumbnail:nth-child(4n+0)
{
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

you can use this css to add extra css each 4 div in each row